# How to calculate the potential number of crawled items for SharePoint 2010 FAST Search?

Tags: search, fast-search

If you were to do the capacity planning for SharePoint 2010 FAST Search I need to know the potential number of crawled items. How do I come about this number without having to actually crawl? Is there any way to find the total number of items using powershell or something?

Comment: Which content sources do you have? Internet sites? Sharepoint sites? Mail server? Databases? File server? Do you have access to all systems that should be crawled?

Comment: SharePoint sites only. Yup, I have complete access to the farm.

Answer (score 1):

If you check out the difference scenarios on http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff599526.aspx they all specify how many items were indexed from SharePoint and what disk space it took.

For example the medium scenario had 4.5 million SharePoint items used 2TB of disk for the content database.

Answer (score 0):

Of course this can be calculated due to powershell, as you stated that you have full access to your SharePoint farm. But did you already determine what data that you want to index: every single sharepoint page, list, list item and document, or a subset of it? Do you really want to index all allitems.aspx pages, editpages? If you have that clear, then you can write a script to analyze your current amount of data. don't forget to determine the expected growth, and base your configuration on that information.

Comment: Can you please suggest me the command to count the total items to be crawled?